# Is this a model of incidence geometry?

Tags: geometry, logic, euclidean-geometry

given the 4 axioms to satisfy what a model is:

A1. there exist at least three distinct noncollinear points

A2. given any two distinct points, there is at least one line that contains both of them.

A3. given any two distinct points there is at most one line that contains both of them.

A4. given any line, there are at least two distinct points that lie on it.

the model in question:
***point*** means an ordinary line containing the origin in 3d sapce; ***line*** means an ordinary plane containing the origin in 3d space; ***lies on*** means "is contained in."

so I'd need to change the axioms to fit the models interpretation and see if the model satisfies each axiom.

A1. there exist at least three distinct noncollinear ***lines***

A2. given any two distinct ***lines***, there is at least one ***plane*** that contains both of them.

A3. given any two distinct ***lines*** there is at most one ***plane*** that contains both of them.

A4. given any ***plane***, there are at least two distinct ***lines*** that lie on it.

My thoughts:
I believe A1 is satisfied because it's in 3d space so there can exist lines x,y,z are not on the same plane *l*.
A2 is satisfied because any two lines intersect the origin which can form a plane.
A3. I'm not sure on if its satisfied, but I believe it's not possible to construct a 2nd plane sharing two lines unless plane *d* = plane *e* so that they are overlapping, as if they a single plane, or intersecting at every line, if that makes sense, so it would be satisfied.
A4 is satisfied because every plane, by definition is constructed of at least two lines

thanks for the help, it's sort of difficult to wrap my brain around changing the definition of the axioms going up 1 dimension.

Comment: It is well-known that given three non-collinear points, there is a unique plane passing through them.